# How to use NumPy array with ctypes?

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I am still writing on a python interface for my c code with ctypes. Today I substituted my file reading function with a python version, which was programmed by somebody else using NumPy. The 'old' c version was called with a `byref(p_data)` while `p_data=PFloat()` (see below). The main function takes the `p_data`.

Old file reading:

```
p_data=POINTER(c_float)
foo.read(filename,byref(p_data))
result=foo.pymain(p_data)
```

The python file reading function, on the other hand, returns a NumPy array. My question now is:

How do I convert a NumPy array to `POINTER(c_float)`?

I googled but only found the other way around: [C arrays through ctypes accessed as NumPy arrays](http://www.kloss-familie.de/blog/article.php?story=20090114054107645) and things I didn't understand: [C-Types Foreign Function Interface (numpy.ctypeslib)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html)

**[update]**
corrected a mistake in the example code

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your code looks like it has some confusion in it -- `ctypes.POINTER()` creates a new ctypes pointer *class*, not a ctypes instance.  Anyway, the easiest way to pass a NumPy array to ctypes code is to use the `numpy.ndarray`'s `ctypes` attribute's `data_as` method.  Just make sure the underlying data is the right type first.  For example:

```
import ctypes
import numpy
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
data = numpy.array([[0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3]])
data = data.astype(numpy.float32)
data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
```

Comment: Are numpy arrays always contiguous after doing the above steps?

Comment: @grabbag The underlying backing memory for an ndarray is always contiguous, so yes, though that may not be exactly what you need to know.  To handle arrays generically you'll need to interpret the `.shape` and `.strides` properties of the `.ctypes` object, and note the caveats on both `.data` and `.data_as()` in the documentation.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html

Answer (score 13):

## Using `np.ndarrays` as `ctypes` arguments

The preferable approach is using `ndpointer`, as mentioned in the [numpy-docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer).

> This approach is more flexible than using, for example,
> POINTER(c_double), since several restrictions can be specified, which
> are verified upon calling the ctypes function. These include data
> type, number of dimensions, shape and flags. If a given array does not
> satisfy the specified restrictions, a TypeError is raised.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

Calling [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) from python. Eventually the filename of the standard C-library `libc.so.6` needs to be adjusted.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

n_bytes_f64 = 8
nrows = 2
ncols = 5

clib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

clib.memcpy.argtypes = [
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=2, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'),
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'),
    ctypes.c_size_t]
clib.memcpy.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

arr_from = np.arange(nrows * ncols).astype(np.float64)
arr_to = np.empty(shape=(nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float64)

print('arr_from:', arr_from)
print('arr_to:', arr_to)

print('\ncalling clib.memcpy ...\n')
clib.memcpy(arr_to, arr_from, nrows * ncols * n_bytes_f64)

print('arr_from:', arr_from)
print('arr_to:', arr_to)
```

**Output**

```
arr_from: [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
arr_to: [[0.0e+000 4.9e-324 9.9e-324 1.5e-323 2.0e-323]
 [2.5e-323 3.0e-323 3.5e-323 4.0e-323 4.4e-323]]

calling clib.memcpy ...

arr_from: [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
arr_to: [[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]]
```

If you modify the `ndim=1/2` arguments of `ndpointer` to be inconsistent with the dimensions of `arr_from/arr_to`, the code fails with an `ArgumentError`.

As the title of this question is quite general, ...

## Constructing a `np.ndarray` from a `ctypes.c_void_p` result

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

In the following example, some memory is allocated by [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and filled with 0s by [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/). Then a numpy array is constructed, to access this memory. Of course the occur some ownership issues, as python will not free memory, which was allocated in c. To avoid **memory leaks**, one has to [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) the allocated memory again by ctypes. The [copy](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy) method can be used for the `np.ndarray` to acquire **ownership**.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

n_bytes_int = 4
size = 7

clib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

clib.malloc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_size_t]
clib.malloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

clib.memset.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_size_t]
clib.memset.restype = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(
    dtype=np.int32, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')

clib.free.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
clib.free.restype = ctypes.c_void_p


pntr = clib.malloc(size * n_bytes_int)
ndpntr = clib.memset(pntr, 0, size * n_bytes_int)
print(type(ndpntr))
ctypes_pntr = ctypes.cast(ndpntr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
print(type(ctypes_pntr))
print()
arr_noowner = np.ctypeslib.as_array(ctypes_pntr, shape=(size,))
arr_owner = np.ctypeslib.as_array(ctypes_pntr, shape=(size,)).copy()
# arr_owner = arr_noowner.copy()


print('arr_noowner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_noowner.ctypes.data, arr_noowner))
print('arr_owner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_owner.ctypes.data, arr_owner))

print('\nfree allocated memory again ...\n')
_ = clib.free(pntr)

print('arr_noowner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_noowner.ctypes.data, arr_noowner))
print('arr_owner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_owner.ctypes.data, arr_owner))

print('\njust for fun: free some python-memory ...\n')
_ = clib.free(arr_owner.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p))

print('arr_noowner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_noowner.ctypes.data, arr_noowner))
print('arr_owner (at {:}): {:}'.format(arr_owner.ctypes.data, arr_owner))
```

**Output**

```
<class 'numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer_<i4_1d_C_CONTIGUOUS'>
<class '__main__.LP_c_int'>

arr_noowner (at 104719884831376): [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
arr_owner (at 104719884827744): [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

free allocated memory again ...

arr_noowner (at 104719884831376): [ -7687536     24381 -28516336     24381         0         0         0]
arr_owner (at 104719884827744): [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

just for fun: free some python-memory ...

arr_noowner (at 104719884831376): [ -7687536     24381 -28516336     24381         0         0         0]
arr_owner (at 104719884827744): [ -7779696     24381 -28516336     24381         0         0         0]
```