# how to get the memory address of a numpy array for C

Tags: python, numpy

I constructed an numpy array::

```
a=np.ndarray([2,3])
```

then i want to see where its data are::

```
a.data 
>>>Out[213]: <read-write buffer for 0x0482C1D0, size 48, offset 0 at 0x049E87A0> 
a.data 
>>>Out[214]: <read-write buffer for 0x0482C1D0, size 48, offset 0 at 0x049E82A0> 
a.data 
>>>Out[215]: <read-write buffer for 0x0482C1D0, size 48, offset 0 at 0x049E81C0>
```

...

why every time the offset address is different?
if i want to transfer the data to a c function using c_types by::

```
ctypes_array = (ctypes.c_char * a.size * 8).from_address(ptr)
```

how should i get the value of ptr?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/3671889/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Also, have a look at [`ndarray.__array_interface__`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html), which is a dict that contains all of the information you're after.

In your case,

```
pointer, read_only_flag = a.__array_interface__['data']
```

Comment: Glad it helped! It may not be the best or most effective way to do it, though.  As J.F.Sebastian mentioned, have a look at `numpy.ctypeslib` (Though if I recall correctly, it uses the `__array_interface__`, as well.).

Comment: @Joe The result of `a.__array_interface__['data']` is not equal to the address in the echo of `a.data`, like following `>>>a=array([(1,2)])    
>>> a.data    
<read-write buffer for 0x8b174c0, size 8, offset 0 at 0x8af6120>
>>> print hex(a.__array_interface__['data'][0])
0x893ff38`

Comment: @Samuel - That's because `a.data` is a `buffer` object, rather than the the actual memory buffer itself. Notice that a new, different buffer object is created each time you call `a.data` (as J.F. Sebastian notes in his answer). Have a look at: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer

Comment: That's bad practice because, obviously, `__array_interface__` is a hidden and undocumented field which may be changed in future versions without any warning. But numpy arrays have `ctypes.get_data()` method which returns the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`a.data` might be a property whose getter function creates a new buffer object (meta data) on each call.

To get the address see how [`numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blame/master/numpy/ctypeslib.py) is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy currently has documented [interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html) to get raw pointer address to an array like this:

```
a = np.asarray([2, 3])
address = a.ctypes.data
```