# Get pointer from numpy array to send image to C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, pointers

I am working on a project on which I have to deal with images between **Python** and **C++**. In order to send an image from C++ to Python, I send a pointer on the first pixel of my image (being a `Mat` object from `OpenCV` library) and in Python with two for loops I used this pointer to create a 2D numpy array.

But I don't succeed to do the same in the other way : get the memory address of the first pixel of the numpy 2D array (an image) and pass it to the C++.

Assume x is my image (2D numpy array), I tried solution like :

- `x.__array_interface__['data'][0]` but this give an integer, not an address
- `x.data` which give different values each time I call it because it gives me the address of a temporary buffer, not the image itself

Thank you in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"send an image between Python and C++"*? Are you using sockets, or message queues or some type of shared memory?

Comment: I want to read image in Python, and send it to C++ to perform operation on C++. So I have to find a way to do it, and I use a pointer for that. But I found the way to do it using #ralf answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a "simple" way to do that:

In **C++**, the function has to take as argument a `void * ptr`, and like this I can create a Mat object using the pointer sent from Python :

```
void myCfunction(void* ptr){
    Mat matrix = Mat(sizes, CV_8UC1, (uchar*)ptr);
}
```

And, in **Python**, use `__array_interface__` to get the memory address (in int type, weird) :

```
mydll.myFunction(myNumpyArray.__array_interface__['data'][0], ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

in [how to get the memory address of a numpy array for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264838/how-to-get-the-memory-address-of-a-numpy-array-for-c/11266170) is also used [`__array_interface__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html), the integer that is returned is a pointer to the *data segment* of the array and no memory address :

> **data (optional)**
>
> A 2-tuple whose first argument is an integer (a long integer if necessary) **that points to the data-area storing the array contents.
>   This pointer must point to the first element of data (in other words
>   any offset is always ignored in this case)**. The second entry in the
>   tuple is a read-only flag (true means the data area is read-only).
>
> This attribute can also be an object exposing the buffer interface which will be used to share the data. If this key is not present (or
>   returns None), then memory sharing will be done through the buffer
>   interface of the object itself. In this case, the offset key can be
>   used to indicate the start of the buffer. A reference to the object
>   exposing the array interface must be stored by the new object if the
>   memory area is to be secured.
>
> Default: None

source :  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html

you can see the content of the entire dictionary returned by `__array_interface__` with `print x.__array_interface__[]`

`__array_struct__` contains a distinct C pointer to the first element of the array, you can access it from within your C(++) code, example is in http://blog.audio-tk.com/2008/11/04/exposing-an-array-interface-with-swig-for-a-cc-structure/:

`

> **C-struct access**
>
> This approach to the array interface allows for faster access to an
>   array using only one attribute lookup and a well-defined C-structure.
>
> `__array_struct__`
>
> A :c:type: PyCObject whose voidptr member contains a pointer to a filled PyArrayInterface structure. Memory for the structure is
>   dynamically created and the PyCObject is also created with an
>   appropriate destructor so the retriever of this attribute simply has
>   to apply Py_DECREF to the object returned by this attribute when it is
>   finished. Also, either the data needs to be copied out, or a reference
>   to the object exposing this attribute must be held to ensure the data
>   is not freed. Objects exposing the `__array_struct__` interface must
>   also not reallocate their memory if other objects are referencing
>   them.
>
> The PyArrayInterface structure is defined in `numpy/ndarrayobject.h` as:

```
typedef struct {
  int two;              /* contains the integer 2 -- simple sanity check */
  int nd;               /* number of dimensions */
  char typekind;        /* kind in array --- character code of typestr */
  int itemsize;         /* size of each element */
  int flags;            /* flags indicating how the data should be interpreted */
                        /*   must set ARR_HAS_DESCR bit to validate descr */
  Py_intptr_t *shape;   /* A length-nd array of shape information */
  Py_intptr_t *strides; /* A length-nd array of stride information */
  void *data;          --------> /* A pointer to the first element of the array */ < ------
  PyObject *descr;      /* NULL or data-description (same as descr key
                                of __array_interface__) -- must set ARR_HAS_DESCR
                                flag or this will be ignored. */
} PyArrayInterface;
```

source :  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this that I am aware of:

- `hex(x.__array_interface__['data'][0])`
- `hex(x.ctypes.data)`

Note that in both cases, `hex` function is used to convert decimal memory address into hexadecimal representation.