# Multi-Dimensional array returned from C++ sends garbage when using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I'm making a Game Engine in Python. Currently it runs at 5-7 FPS, and I want to increase it. So I thought to use C/C++ for putting shapes onto frames. My frames are 3-Dimensional arrays. I want to transport theses arrays between python and C++. But When using `np.ctypeslib.ndpointer` the array contains garbage.

Here's the code of C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int*** zeros_3d_cpp(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    int ***arr = new int**[n1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int*[n2];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = new int[n3];
            for (int k = 0; k < n3; k++) {
                arr[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int*** zeros_3d(int n1, int n2, int n3) { return zeros_3d_cpp(n1, n2, n3); }
}
```

Here's the python code:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./bin/main.dll')

lib.zeros_3d.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_int]
lib.zeros_3d.restype = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=c_int, ndim=3, shape=(3, 2, 4))

print(lib.zeros_3d(3, 2, 4))
```

And the generated output is:

```
[[[  4490944         0   4491040         0]
  [  4491136         0 387641098 268496650]]

 [[  4490976         0   4491008         0]
  [  4456792         0 387641098 268496650]]

 [[        0         0         0         0]
  [  4456792         0 387641098 268496650]]]
```

While it should be **0** all over.

Please Help me fast I want to finish this project before my school opens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to store frames in a Multi-Dimensional array as you mentioned. It would be easier to store the data in a linear 1-D array.

```
int*** zeros_3d_cpp(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    int ***arr = new int**[n1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int*[n2];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = new int[n3];
            for (int k = 0; k < n3; k++) {
                arr[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I would split the code into 2 parts, first allocating Array and then fill it up.

```
int* zeros_3d_cpp(int width, int height, int breadth) {
    //Allocating Memory
    int *arr = new int[width*height*breadth];

    for (int i = 0; i < breadth; i++) 
    {
        //Iterates over 2D Image
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) 
        {
            //Iterates over a Single Row
            for (int k = 0; k < width; k++) 
            {
                arr[i*width*height + j*width +k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Make sure to bind the memory (ie) the returned array ptr to some object in python.

**Memory**

Also you are using Raw Pointers, use extra precaution to see who is managing the memory of the resource. You can allocate the memory (Dynamic Array in your case) from python side using numpy or allocate from C++ and track the object lifetime in Python to make sure it's freed correctly.

You can also create the array in python using numpy and then return the pointer into C++ and so your C++ function would take the starting pointer address as input

```
void zeros_3d_cpp(int* start_address, int width, int height, int breadth) {
 //Only fill in with zeros
}
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but converting a 1080x1920x3 array to 1d and back is too much of over head and even slows down the code more. I've even tried ```np.array.reshape``` it does'nt help either.

Comment: And I am not storing frames it's the pixel grid which is to be displayed onto the screen and cv2 accepts only multidimensional arrays.

Comment: you don't have to convert. In your example you allocate memory in C++, rather try to get the memory numpy allocates. OpenCV Mat stores images linearly for 2D. If your 3D Frames are packed 2D Frames, use Array of Imgs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036850/get-pointer-from-numpy-array-to-send-image-to-c came across, seems like a common problem. AFAIK both numpy and OpenCV2 store Data in Row-Major order inside as a linear data. You can access them straight