# Python: memory corruption after successful return from a ctypes foreign function

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

**Non-essential background**: I am having a multitude of problems with `ctypes` pointers that I have so far been able to work around by stripping everything down to a `c_void_p` on the Python side, then digging out what I need in C via recasting and pointer arithmetic. However, I've finally hit a wall in Python that I can't work around and I'm hoping that the sage answers to this MWE allow me to fix all of my other hacks.

**The MWE**: In both of the cases below, I successfully define, populate, pass, and return a struct from/to Python to/from a simple C foreign function. In the first case (`ff1.py`), everything is fine. In the second case (`ff2.py`), the function returns and successfully dereferences in Python, then Python crashes. The difference between the two cases is whether the struct that is passed out from Python is imported as a variable from a module or whether it is returned from a Python function before being passed to C.

`ff.h`:

```cpp
struct dummy
{
  int      dim1;
  int      dim2;
  double * array_ptr;
};

void
foreign_func( struct dummy * ptr_to_dummy );
```

`ff.c`:

```cpp
#include "ff.h"

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
void
foreign_func( struct dummy * d_ptr )
{
  const int N = d_ptr->dim1;
  const int M = d_ptr->dim2;

  for( int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    for( int j=0; j<M; j++ )
      d_ptr->array_ptr[ i*M + j ] *= 3.14159;

  return;
}
```

`struct_wo_funcs.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class dummy_struct_type( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ( 'dim1',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'dim2',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'array_ptr', ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_double ) ) ]

n = 12
m = 50
a = np.ones( (n,m), dtype=ctypes.c_double, order='C' )

dummy_struct_instance = \
        dummy_struct_type( ctypes.c_int( n ),
                           ctypes.c_int( m ),
                           a.ctypes.data_as( ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_double ) ) )
```

`struct_w_funcs.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class dummy_struct_type( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ( 'dim1',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'dim2',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'array_ptr', ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_double ) ) ]

def make_instance( n, m ):
    a = np.ones( (n,m), dtype=ctypes.c_double, order='C' )

    return dummy_struct_type( ctypes.c_int( n ),
                              ctypes.c_int( m ),
                              a.ctypes.data_as( ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_double ) ) )
```

`ff1.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import os
from struct_wo_funcs import dummy_struct_type, dummy_struct_instance

fflib = ctypes.CDLL( os.path.abspath( 'ff_lib.so' ) )

fflib.foreign_func.argtypes = [ ctypes.POINTER( dummy_struct_type ) ]
fflib.foreign_func.restype  = None

fflib.foreign_func( ctypes.byref( dummy_struct_instance ) )

print( dummy_struct_instance.array_ptr[19] )
```

`ff2.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import os
from struct_w_funcs import dummy_struct_type, make_instance

fflib = ctypes.CDLL( os.path.abspath( 'ff_lib.so' ) )

fflib.foreign_func.argtypes = [ ctypes.POINTER( dummy_struct_type ) ]
fflib.foreign_func.restype  = None

dummy_struct_instance = make_instance( 12, 50 )

fflib.foreign_func( ctypes.byref( dummy_struct_instance ) )

print( dummy_struct_instance.array_ptr[19] )
```

I have tried this with a variety of compilers on Linux. I have also changed the export and compiled with gcc/MinGW and cl/MSVC on Windows, all to the same effect. (To be fair, running at the MSVC developer prompt does not result in an outright crash; rather, Windows flinches for a while, then recovers back to the prompt without reporting anything.) Here is a representative Linux crash with gcc v7.5.0 and Python 3.6.9:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c ff.c && gcc -fPIC -shared -o ff_lib.so ff.o

$ python3 ff1.py
3.14159

$ python3 ff2.py
3.14159
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have `valgrind`ed the heck out of this and can only learn that something is wrong in the guts of Python. Ultimately, I want to be able to use functions in Python to generate the structs that I pass out; that is, I wish `ff2.py` would not crash. If your answer is simply another work-around (like some magic combination of `numpy` declarations and `byref`s, etc.), that is good enough for me. As far as I know, this is a problem with Python and not C, but if you can get it to work by altering the C side of the FFI, I'd love to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ctypes pointer to your array data does not keep the array alive. You can make the first one crash with by just `del a`.

Create a wrapper for the struct that also keeps the numpy array alive by holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

@antti-haapala Sure enough! Here is my working version:

`struct_w_wrapper.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class dummy_struct_type( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ( 'dim1',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'dim2',      ctypes.c_int ),
                 ( 'array_ptr', ctypes.POINTER( ctypes.c_double ) ) ]

##
##  the wrapper
##   the arguments are obviously tailored to
##   dummy_struct_type, not to an arbitrary
##   "struct_to_be_wrapped"
##
def dont_free_me( struct_to_be_wrapped ):
    class wrapper:
        def __init__( self, dim1, dim2, arr ):
            self.dim1   = dim1  ##  these two ints should persist
            self.dim2   = dim2  ##  without wrapping, but whatever
            self.arr    = arr
            self.struct = \
                    struct_to_be_wrapped( ctypes.c_int( dim1 ),
                                          ctypes.c_int( dim2 ),
                                          arr.ctypes.data_as(
                                              ctypes.POINTER(
                                                  ctypes.c_double )))
        def the_struct( self ):
            return self.struct

    return wrapper
                                                

wrapped_dummy_struct_type = dont_free_me( dummy_struct_type )

def make_instance( n, m ):
    a = np.ones( (n,m), dtype=ctypes.c_double, order='C' )

    return wrapped_dummy_struct_type( n, m, a )
```

`ff3.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import os
from struct_w_wrapper import dummy_struct_type, make_instance

fflib = ctypes.CDLL( os.path.abspath( 'ff_lib.so' ) )

fflib.foreign_func.argtypes = [ ctypes.POINTER( dummy_struct_type ) ]
fflib.foreign_func.restype  = None

wrapped_dummy_struct_instance = make_instance( 12, 50 )
dummy_struct_instance = wrapped_dummy_struct_instance.the_struct()

fflib.foreign_func( ctypes.byref( dummy_struct_instance ) )

print( dummy_struct_instance.array_ptr[19] )
```

Then, from the prompt:

```
$ python3 ff3.py 
3.14159
```

UPDATE: I now know that this is an old, known feature ([#12836](https://bugs.python.org/issue12836)) in Python ctypes for which [numpy's ctypes interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html) has a built-in workaround. There is a `data` method which mirrors the problematic `data_as` behavior in this SO question; there is also numpy's own `data_as` method with what we want here: "The returned pointer will keep a reference to the array."

Since my problem results in a crash, I started a Python bug ([#41883](https://bugs.python.org/issue41883)), which has some good discussion if you are interested in implementing your own workaround. [This other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671889/11924662) is also good reading.